# What is standard function like a kbhit?

Tags: c, standards

I heard kbhit is not a standard.

Where is standard function for keyboard check?

Please help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: As of ANSI C standard, nothing. As of POSIX, see `tcsetattr` family of functions (together with non-blocking IO). As of Windows, see platform-specific `PeekConsoleInput` and friends.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard does not exist in standard [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29). It only knows about [`stdin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) (and a lot of computers don't have keyboards).

Keyboard access is operating system specific. See [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) for an historical and Unix centered approach.